# Azure AD B2C - Unable to fix the OrchestrationStep depending upon the conditional true/false

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am facing one weird issue while putting steps in OrchestrationStep.

I have a requirement to allow or deny user login depending upon user IP address. I am calling an API to check user and IP information and return a boolean type.

[image]

Now, I want to make a decision based on BlockSignIn variable value returned by API. I am calling API on step 2(shown in the below steps.)

Step 3 is to make a decision, whether to allow login or not depending on the value of `BlockSignIn`

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
  <ClaimsExchange Id="ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>BlockSignIn</Value>
      <Value>true</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="BlockUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Selfasserted-Blockuser" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

These are my OrchestrationSteps sequence.

Scenarios:

If I return `BlockSignIn = true`, then it shows me a page with a message that my IP is blocked.

If I return `BlockSignIn = false`, then it gave me a Server Error with the below details. I am not sure where to check the further details.

> AADB2C: An exception has occurred.
>
> Correlation ID: 7a031ab6-0bca-4820-afd2-597b09b975b4
>
> Timestamp: <>

If I update Orchestration step 3 to set to `<Value>false</Value>`, then it blocks login on returning `true` from API  but gives a similar error on returning `false` from API.

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>BlockSignIn</Value>
      <Value>false</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="BlockUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Selfasserted-Blockuser" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

I want to achieve below results:

1. If API returns `true`(for BlockSignIn), then show the error page.
2. If API returns `false`(for BlockSignIn), then proceed further with
   the next steps to log in.

Can someone guide me, please?

Comment: In terms of the exception, use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Like rbrayb says, you really need to track down where exactly the exception's happening using App Insights. Most likely it's not a problem with the posted code but with something that's happening after it which could be anything, depending on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "BlockSignIn" is a boolean claim. Try change your precondition value **True** or **Flase**:

Eg:

```
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>BlockSignIn</Value>
      <Value>True</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
 </Precondition>
```

For more details please go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#precondition).